# Double Colon Operator not working on JUnit

Tags: java, junit5

I'm working with WebFlux Project with JDK11.
And I'm using Emacs and lsp-java as my IDE.

When I run test with Gradle commands, it works.
But When I run with `dap-java-run`, it throws `java.lang.IllegalAccessException`.

There was double-colon operator in the code where it throws exceptions.
So I changed code to a lambda expression and it works.

I'm not good at JVM environment. So I don't know where I should start to debug.

Code with a double colon operator:

```java
.flatMap(userRepository::findOneWithAuthoritiesById)
```

Code passed with `dap-java-run`.

```
.flatMap(id -> userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesById(id))
```

dap-java-run commands.:

```bash
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=50082 -jar ~/.emacs.d/eclipse.jdt.ls/test-runner/junit-platform-console-standalone.jar -cp $JUNIT_CLASS_PATH -c [CLASSNAME]
```

Exception logs:

```
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: bootstrap method initialization exception
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:194)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:307)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:258)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:248)
    at ***.***.UserService.updateUser(UserService.java:*)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:*)
    at ***.***.UserService.updateUser(UserService.java:*)
    at ***.***.UserService.lambda$13(UserService.java:*)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onNext(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:292)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:236)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:89)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:846)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.innerComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:894)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:997)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.deferredComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:392)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$CommitInner.onComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:527)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:384)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMapMany.java:260)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:181)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandle.java:220)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:846)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:465)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBuffer$BufferExactSubscriber.onComplete(FluxBuffer.java:187)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2058)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.deferredComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:392)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$CommitInner.onComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:527)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2058)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2058)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:209)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:209)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.maybeRecycleAndDrain(SimpleDequePool.java:533)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool$QueuePoolRecyclerInner.onComplete(SimpleDequePool.java:765)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool$QueuePoolRecyclerMono.subscribe(SimpleDequePool.java:877)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:89)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandle.java:220)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1817)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.subscribe(MonoCallable.java:62)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onError(MonoIgnoreElements.java:84)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onError(FluxFilter.java:157)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxFilter.java:291)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:265)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:384)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:846)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:465)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:549)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:152)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:294)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:230)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:649)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:633)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onSubscribe(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:115)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:200)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(FluxFlatMap.java:93)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8455)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$ResourceSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsingWhen.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onNext(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onNext(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetry$RetrySubscriber.onNext(FluxRetry.java:87)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249)
    at io.r2dbc.pool.MonoDiscardOnCancel$MonoDiscardOnCancelSubscriber.onNext(MonoDiscardOnCancel.java:92)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:292)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:236)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:89)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandle.java:220)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1817)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.subscribe(MonoCallable.java:62)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at io.r2dbc.pool.MonoDiscardOnCancel.subscribe(MonoDiscardOnCancel.java:50)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
    at reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.deliver(AbstractPool.java:469)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.lambda$drainLoop$8(SimpleDequePool.java:370)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.ImmediateScheduler.schedule(ImmediateScheduler.java:52)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.drainLoop(SimpleDequePool.java:370)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.pendingOffer(SimpleDequePool.java:600)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.doAcquire(SimpleDequePool.java:296)
    at reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.request(AbstractPool.java:432)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool$QueueBorrowerMono.subscribe(SimpleDequePool.java:720)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetry$RetrySubscriber.resubscribe(FluxRetry.java:117)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetry.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetry.java:50)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4385)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen.subscribe(FluxUsingWhen.java:104)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoUsingWhen.subscribe(MonoUsingWhen.java:87)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1706)
    at ***.***.MemberServiceTest.regDealerByStoreOwner(MemberServiceTest.java:*)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.SameThreadTimeoutInvocation.proceed(SameThreadTimeoutInvocation.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.junit.platform.console.tasks.ConsoleTestExecutor.executeTests(ConsoleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.console.tasks.ConsoleTestExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ConsoleTestExecutor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.console.tasks.CustomContextClassLoaderExecutor.replaceThreadContextClassLoaderAndInvoke(CustomContextClassLoaderExecutor.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.console.tasks.CustomContextClassLoaderExecutor.invoke(CustomContextClassLoaderExecutor.java:31)
    at org.junit.platform.console.tasks.ConsoleTestExecutor.execute(ConsoleTestExecutor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher.executeTests(ConsoleLauncher.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher.execute(ConsoleLauncher.java:82)
    at org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher.execute(ConsoleLauncher.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher.execute(ConsoleLauncher.java:48)
    at org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher.main(ConsoleLauncher.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class is not public: ***.***.repo.UserRepositoryInternal.findOneWithAuthoritiesById(String)Mono/invokeInterface, from ***.***.UserService (unnamed module @1f0f92f5)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.revealDirect(MethodHandles.java:2004)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.<init>(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:133)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.<init>(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:159)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:324)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:127)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:307)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:258)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:248)
    at ***.***.UserService.updateUser(UserService.java:*)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:710)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.InstrumentationMemberAccessor$Dispatcher$ByteBuddy$T591TQoj.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.InstrumentationMemberAccessor.invoke(InstrumentationMemberAccessor.java:239)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.ModuleMemberAccessor.invoke(ModuleMemberAccessor.java:55)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodAdvice.tryInvoke(MockMethodAdvice.java:318)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodAdvice.access$500(MockMethodAdvice.java:64)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodAdvice$RealMethodCall.invoke(MockMethodAdvice.java:238)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.InterceptedInvocation.callRealMethod(InterceptedInvocation.java:142)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.answers.CallsRealMethods.answer(CallsRealMethods.java:45)
    at org.mockito.Answers.answer(Answers.java:90)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:111)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:34)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodAdvice.handle(MockMethodAdvice.java:134)
    ... 251 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class is not public: ***.***.repo.UserRepositoryInternal.findOneWithAuthoritiesById(String)Mono/invokeInterface, from ***.***.UserService (unnamed module @1f0f92f5)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:942)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.checkAccess(MethodHandles.java:2201)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.revealDirect(MethodHandles.java:2001)
    ... 274 common frames omitted
```

Comment: This smells like it might just be a bug in the JVM. What *specific* version are you running (and compiling) this on? Alternatively, it could be some odd interaction of Spring creating proxy objects and the JVM not feeling so good about it (i.e. a bug in either Spring *or* the JVM *or* both).

Comment: I'm using temurin64-11.0.16.1 and springBoot 2.6.6. I'll try with other version of JVM. But if it's bug of spring, how can I configure out it is?

Comment: I tested with `oracle64-11.0.16`, `zulu64-11.0.16.1`.
And all results are same. I don't know from where I should start to debug.